# Custom windowtitle + toolbar (ala. Mac App Store and Reeder for Mac)

Tags: objective-c, macos, toolbar, nswindow, appkit

I'm trying to figure out how to create the "new popular" combined window title and toolbar as seen in Reeder for Mac and Mac App Store (http://www.apple.com/mac/app-store/). Tried googling but this does not seem to be a very discussed topic!

Basically; is it a borderless window with custom views all the way (and in such case, how do I get working traffic-light buttons)? Or is it possible to do with Interface Builder?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

https://github.com/indragiek/INAppStoreWindow

Answer (score 1):

`class-dump`ing Reeder reveals that the window title bar is, in fact, just a view (so yes, borderless window with custom views - the bottom bar is a view as well). I'm assuming Apple does the same thing, but who knows? Maybe this behavior will become more standard in 10.7 and gain official support?

Comment: I'm betting it will, due to the appearance of the Mac App store in screenies.  Not sure I like it, but it's going to be the new norm in Lion I think.

Comment: Ah, cool didn't know you could do that!
Thanks! :) Guess I'll have to figure out how to recreate the window buttons and such then!

Comment: Yeah, good luck with that (poke around AppKit a little bit, and I think you'll figure out how to do it)... ;)